# Cropped image DPI issue in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, imagick

I change uploaded image size using `intermediate_image_sizes_advanced` function.
In that when I add any files in media in local that all cropped image DPI is 96 but when I upload media in live than no change in image DPI.
I also use `imagick` for change image DPI for live uploaded image but not worked on live but working fine in localhost.

Comment: If it works locally and doesn't work on your server, you should make sure you're running the same version of the software on both.

Comment: For local and live only change is PHP version is there any effect for that reason?